# Applying XML Namespaces without Prefixes in XML Doc

Tags: apex, xml, xmlnode

I am still relatively new to XML in Apex and I am trying to reproduce the following XML:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
                <u:Created>2019-10-22T17:00:03.259Z</u:Created>
                <u:Expires>2019-10-22T17:05:03.259Z</u:Expires>
            </u:Timestamp>
            <o:UsernameToken u:Id="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
                <o:Username>xxxxxxxxxxxx</o:Username>
                <o:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText"> xxxxxxxxxxxxx</o:Password>
            </o:UsernameToken>
        </o:Security>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <Parent xmlns="https://www.provexchnet.com/dsi">
            <child xmlns:a="http://urlone.org" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <a:Grandchild>REGISTER</a:Grandchild>
            </child>
        </Parent>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

The issues I am having are:

- Setting a namespace on Parent without the prefix (do I just set an
  attribute?)
- How do set a namespace with prefix "a" on child without
  the node showing up as `<a:child>`?
- How do I apply the "a:" to the
  Grandchild node?

(Apologies for the formatting, I can't seem to get it into one code block)

Comment: This XML is only a fragment, and thus you cannot directly craft it using Dom.Document. Please include the full and proper XML.

Comment: I have added the rest. It should be in one code block, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: There was a missing space. I've reformatted this for you.